# RxJava - Continue infinite stream

Tags: rx-java

I saw the other similar issue, but it did not solve my problem:

```
        Observable<Integer> resumeSequence = Observable.just(-1);       
        Observable.just(1,0,2,5)
          .flatMap(x -> 
                      Observable.just(10/x)
                      //.onErrorReturn(error -> -1)
                      .onErrorResumeNext(resumeSequence)
                      .onExceptionResumeNext(resumeSequence)
              )
//        .onErrorReturn(error -> -1)
          .onErrorResumeNext(resumeSequence)
          .onExceptionResumeNext(resumeSequence)
          .subscribe(System.out::println, 
                      throwable -> System.out.println("IN ERROR CALLBACK" + throwable));
```

Ideally the Resume should be inside the flatMap. The output should print 4 numbers & flow should not go to the Error Callback.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question, it's clear what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable.just` is useful for already computed values.

your code bellow

```
 Observable.just(1,0,2,5)
      .flatMap(x -> 
                  Observable.just(10/x)
                  .onErrorResumeNext(resumeSequence)
                  .onExceptionResumeNext(resumeSequence)
          )
```

can be rewrited like this :

```
 Observable.just(1,0,2,5)
      .flatMap(x -> {
                  int result = 10 / x;
                  return Observable.just(result)
                  .onErrorResumeNext(resumeSequence)
                  .onExceptionResumeNext(resumeSequence);
          })
```

So it explain that your "primary" `Observable` goes in an error state and complete thanks to `onExceptionResumeNext` operator, as your nested `Observable` won't never be used

What you wants to achieve is to not complete the observable then an error occur. To do this, your nested `Observable` can complete as soon as your primary `Observable` doesn't. To do this, you'll have to defer the computation of `10 / x` using the `fromCallable` operator:

```
 Observable<Integer> resumeSequence = Observable.just(-1);       
 Observable.just(1,0,2,5)
      // 10 / x will be computed only when this nested observable will subscribe
      .flatMap(x -> Observable.fromCompletable(() -> 10/x)
                  .onErrorResumeNext(resumeSequence)
                  .onExceptionResumeNext(resumeSequence)
          )
      .onErrorResumeNext(resumeSequence)
      .onExceptionResumeNext(resumeSequence)
      .subscribe(System.out::println, 
                  throwable -> System.out.println("IN ERROR CALLBACK" + throwable));
```